# Why does using jmp prevent the Clang assembler from figuring out an absolute expression for .fill?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, clang, bootloader

I'm messing around with writing a simple toy boot loader (additional info at bottom of post). The following `nasm` code shows what the bootloader looked like at one point before I tried to switch to Clang. When compiled using `nasm -f bin -o nasm.out boot.asm`, then run using `qemu-system-i386 nasm.out`, prints an endless stream of `!` characters to the screen:

```
bits 16
global main
main:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, '!'
    int 0x10
    jmp main
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0x00
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

I was curious if I could use Clang as my assembler instead of nasm, so I tried translating the program to what I think is the GAS syntax equivalent:

```
.code16
.global main
main:
    mov $0x0e, %ah
    mov $'!', %al
    int $0x10
    jmp main
.fill 510 - (. - main)
.byte 0x55
.byte 0xaa
```

However, when compiled using `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang --target=i386-elf -m16 -c boot.s -o boot.o`, I get the following error:

```
boot.s:9:7: error: expected absolute expression
.fill 510 - (. - main)
      ^
```

Compilation succeeds if `jmp main` is replaced with `jmp *0x00` or a non-`jmp` instruction. It's not strictly equivalent, but it seems to point towards something about the label which is giving Clang issues.

`nasm` didn't have any issues figuring out how many bytes to use for padding. Why does Clang balk when I ask it to do the same? Is there some subtle (or obvious) thing which I missed?

I can always manually figure out how many bytes of padding I need, but that's tedious and error-prone, and seems like something the assembler should be able to do on its own.

I'm running Clang 4.0, installed through Homebrew, on macOS 10.12.6.

---

- Quick bootloader refresher, if you need it: the boot sector is 512 bytes long, and needs to have the values `0x55` and `0xaa` at offsets 510 and 511, respectively. The easy way of ensuring this is to make sure the binary output is exactly 512 bytes long, and has `0x55` and `0xaa` as its last two bytes.

Comment: Could you do me a favour and try jumping to a local label (e.g. `.Lfoo`) instead of `main`? `clang` might get confused because it can't size the jump ahead of time.

Comment: Nope :( `.Lfoo:` and `1:` both before and after the jump result in the same error

Comment: What if you use the local label in the `.fill` expression instead?

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. Adding `.Lfoo` under the `main` label and using that in the `.fill` expression gives the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Apple's assembler. Although the assembler is a single pass, the calculation `. - main` should have resolvable to an absolute value.

You should be able to replace the `.fill` with an `.org 510` directive to advance the location counter 510 bytes from the beginning of the current section. From the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Org.html#Org):

> 7.68 **.org new-lc , fill**
>
> **Advance the location counter of the current section to new-lc**. new-lc is either an absolute expression or an
>   expression with the same section as the current subsection. That is,
>   you can’t use .org to cross sections: if new-lc has the wrong section,
>   the .org directive is ignored. To be compatible with former
>   assemblers, if the section of new-lc is absolute, as issues a warning,
>   then pretends the section of new-lc is the same as the current
>   subsection.
>
> [snip]
>
> Beware that the **origin is relative to the start of the section**, not to
>   the start of the subsection. This is compatible with other people’s
>   assemblers.

This should work:

```
.code16
.global main
main:
    mov $0x0e, %ah
    mov $'!', %al
    int $0x10
    jmp main
.org 510
.byte 0x55
.byte 0xaa
```

I was able to reproduce your problem with `clang-900.0.39.2`, and the usage of `.org` worked with that version.

Answer (score 0):

Clang has its own assembler which doesn't understand all of the GNU assembler syntax. Try to assemble with the GNU assembler instead, i.e. using `as --32 -o boot.o boot.s`, then it should work.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm on macOS, so `as` emits the same error, and it seems that Homebrew doesn't provide an option to install `gas`. Using g++ instead of clang yields the same result, although I think that's because they both use `as` internally.

Comment: @awksp `clang` doesn't use `as` internally. `clang` has its own assembler.

Comment: Er, right. Poor wording on my part. Either way, g++ fails in the exact same way as clang.

Comment: @awksp Note that `g++` is most likely clang, too, on macOS. Check `g++ --version`.

Comment: I was using g++-7, installed through Homebrew. That's a good point, though; if only the fix was as easy as switching to g++...

Comment: @awksp What happens if you use the assembler shipped with macOS directly?